# Counting the number of words in a file

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int hmlines(ifstream &a){
int i=0;
string line;
while (getline(a,line)){
cout << line << endl;
i++;

}
return i;

}


int hmwords(ifstream &a){

int i=0;
char c;
while ((c=a.get()) && (c!=EOF)){
if(c==' '){
i++;
}

}

return i;


}








int main()
{
int l=0;
int w=0;
string filename;
ifstream matos;
start:
cout << "give me the name of the file i wish to count lines, words and chars: ";
cin >> filename;
matos.open(filename.c_str());
if (matos.fail()){
goto start;
}
l = hmlines(matos);
matos.seekg(0, ios::beg);
w = hmwords(matos);
/*c = hmchars(matos);*/
cout << "The # of lines are :" << l << ". The # of words are : " << w ;

matos.close();



}
```

The file that i am trying to open has the following contents.

```
Twinkle, twinkle, little bat!
How I wonder what you're at!
Up above the world you fly,
Like a teatray in the sky.
```

The output i get is:

```
give me the name of the file i wish to count lines, words and chars: ert.txt
Twinkle, twinkle, little bat!
How I wonder what you're at!
Up above the world you fly,
Like a teatray in the sky.
The # of lines are :4. The # of words are : 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int hmwords(ifstream &a){
  int i;
```

You've forgotten to initialize `i`. It can contain absolutely anything at that point.

Also note that `operator>>` on streams skips whitespace by default. Your word counting loop needs the `noskipws` modifier.

```
  a >> noskipws >> c;
```

Another problem is that after you call `hmlines`, `matos` is at end of stream. You need to reset it if you want to read the file again. Try something like:

```
l = hmlines(matos);
matos.clear();
matos.seekg(0, ios::beg);
w = hmwords(matos);
```

(The `clear()` is necessary, otherwise `seekg` has no effect.)

Comment: Once i did that now my word counter function gives me 0

Comment: @Vaios : You should initialize ALL variables before you use them. If you don't they just get a random value (what ever the memory block that contains the variable happens to be)

Answer (score 4):

Formatted input **eats whitespaces**. You can just count tokens directly:

```
int i = 0;
std::string dummy;

// Count words from the standard input, aka "cat myfile | ./myprog"
while (cin >> dummy) ++i;

// Count files from an input stream "a", aka "./myprog myfile"
while (a >> dummy) ++i;
```

Comment: Whats formatted input??I did change from char to string and i still get 0

Comment: Formatted input uses the `>>` operator. Wait, are you reading from `cin` or from a file? It should have been `while (a >> dummy)` I suppose.